# unable to add record in My-SQL-DB using hibernate+springboot+jpa

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

i'm trying to add record in db in my spring boot application, im using hibernate+jpa.

my model class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="branchpercentage")
public class BranchPercentage{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="percentage")
    private Integer percentage;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="branch")
    private Branch branch;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Integer getPercentage() {
        return percentage;
    }
    public void setPercentage(Integer percentage) {
        this.percentage = percentage;
    }
    public Branch getBranch() {
        return branch;
    }
    public void setBranch(Branch branch) {
        this.branch = branch;
    }

}
```

controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/report")
public ModelAndView home() throws SQLException{
    //for new table record
    Collection<Branch> branchList=branchServiceV1.getBranches();
    BranchComparator branchComp = new BranchComparator();
    List<Branch> list = new ArrayList<Branch>(branchList);
    Collections.sort(list, branchComp);
    branchList=list;
    BranchPercentage b;
    for(Branch branch:branchList){
        b=new BranchPercentage();
        b.setBranch(branch);
        b.setPercentage(5);
        prcntRepository.save(b);
    }


    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    User user = userService.findUserByEmail(auth.getName());
    modelAndView.addObject("userName",user.getName() + " " + user.getLastName() + " (" + user.getEmail() + ")");
    modelAndView.addObject("adminMessage","Content Available Only for Users with Admin Role");
    modelAndView.setViewName("admin/report");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

repository:

```
public interface PrcntRepository  extends CrudRepository<BranchPercentage, Integer> {

    public Collection<BranchPercentage> findById(BranchPercentage id);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    BranchPercentage save (BranchPercentage obj);
}
```

properties file:

> spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/orderonline
>
> spring.datasource.username = root spring.datasource.password = root
>
> spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
>
> spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT  spring.jpa.show-sql = true
>
> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
>
> spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy =
>   org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
>
> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect =
>   org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

```
Branch.java:
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name="branch")
public class Branch implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;    
    @Column(name="town")
    private String town;    
    @Column(name="city")
    private String city;    
    @Column(name="county")
    private String county;

        /* setter and getters */
}
```

but im getting this error

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`o
rderonline`.`branchpercentage`, CONSTRAINT `FK8pxwopwdv21hixfxcapuynnlq` FOREIGN KEY (`branch`) REFERENCES `branch` (`id`))

any idea where i'm doing wrong...?

Comment: can you share Branch code

Comment: yeah sure i can share it

Comment: try to use Generation strategy AUTO in the Branch

Comment: what does @JoinColumn(name = "branch") mean? First thing, it should contain two attributes name and referencedColumnName. name should be the name of the column on which you are joining in this entity. referencedColumnName should be the name of the column in the (Branch) entity.